# How to handle rogue management?

Tags: management, people-management

I recently moved up from a specific team to a global function, moving from an incompetent manager to a very good one. I am in a healthy and productive environment.
However, yesterday my own job description came up in the company's careers page.
Apparently shortly after the move my old manager and her 'collaborators' made arrangements to hire my replacement to work with them directly.

So, now we have a global function, which is providing strategies, procedures and standards for the whole company, and these guys' upcoming resource, which will... I don't know. They are basically internalising my global support role.

I have no idea about how to sort this mess: my boss is protective, but he also didn't tell me about this for weeks. He already has trouble trying to keep together his team now that they are hiring a 'parallel' role.

In the best case, we are having a situation where two people who should be working together work separately; in the worst case, the decrease in my workload might support my departure.

**Edit**: upper management is fighting about internalising a global function, which would be my role. My boss is supportive, but the other side is hiring somebody with exactly my same job description. I am trying to understand if there is anything I can do in such a mess, as I would like to keep my role.

Comment: Only you know what could keep you from quitting. Is there another question implied in your post that could be answered by this community? Please edit to clarify what experience you're hoping to extract from here?

Comment: **By definition *management* can't go rogue**. I'm not sure I see the problem in your post. How is it any concern of yours that your old position is being redefined?

Comment: @Lilienthal The question clear.  Own is old.

Comment: If one management group is defining policies / practices different from the rest of the company, that's something for upper management to deal with. Unless it directly affects you, or is demonstrably illegal, it's not your problem and may not be a problem at all. Walk away and let upper management do _THEIR_ job.

Comment: @Frisbee I'm unsure what you mean, could you rephrase (or join me in chat)?

Comment: His role got moved to a global function.  Same role.  If they do locally what is his global role then the need for the global role is diminished.  "The decrease in my workload might support my departure."

Comment: You have a 'coup' over your role by the sounds of it

Comment: Joe: not really. This time it's not even one person.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your boss is struggling to keep his team together while the rest of the company tries to revert the global changes back to the old regional ways, then you need to get it to the attention of whoever decided to implement the changes in the first place. They are the most likely to have both the authority and the inclination to deal with this properly - or their own work will be undermined.

It just sounds like your old team are trying to protect their old empire.

Comment: yep. My boss outranks all of them, but it's not easy...

Comment: @Monoandale it never is - maybe he needs to centralise a couple of the 'collaborators' roles too, or at least a centralised HR responsibility for hiring - then they will simply not be able to hire a replacement.

Answer (score 3):

There is management problem if your role is moved to a global function and then a group is allowed to make it local function. If it was not supposed to be a global function then why do it in the first place? Sounds like a power struggle that is even above your current boss. I don't think there is anything you can do about it directly. Perform your role and if the workload does go down be willing to take on other roles / tasks.  See how thing go before you quit. Don't try and fix the old department if they don't ask for your help.  At this point you just want to be seen as a solid performer doing what he is told to do.

Is this old manager one of the [how to get rid of an incompetent manager?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/57383/how-to-get-rid-of-an-incompetent-manager)  If so they probably just don't want to work with you.  That level of contempt is not healthy.

Comment: that's exactly the case. the old guy now is 're-hiring me'.